# Storing text box input into an array and displaying it on to a list box in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

What i need to do is take input 10 times from a text box, store it in an array and then display the array onto a list box.

I came up with this for loop but it doesn't work, all it does is display the first input and then the rest are just blank:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            ArrNames(i) = txtUserInput.Text
            txtUserInput.Clear()
        Next i
```

and i have a different button to display the array and i used this:

```
lstDisplay.DataSource = ArrNames
```

can anyone help me? iv'e looked everywhere and nothing worked for me

**Edit 1:**

So i changed it a lot and came up with this:

```
Dim I As Integer

        If sender Is btnEnter Then
            I = I + 1
        End If

        ArrNames(I) = txtUserInput.Text
        txtUserInput.Clear()
```

is what it does is if the button is pressed it increases I by one which makes it so the input goes to the right index right?

but now that i make this it stopped displaying anything at all so this:

```
Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
        lstDisplay.DataSource = ArrNames
```

stopped working

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the questions around here.

Comment: txtUserInput.Clear()  is clearing the text input in the loop after the first.  It needs to be moved outside the loop, after the Next i...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully that `I` variable is declared at class level in the same place as the array.

To force the ListBox to refresh you have to set the `.DataSource` to `Nothing` and then back to your array again:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private I As Integer
    Private ArrNames(9) As String

    Private Sub btnAddName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddName.Click
        If I < ArrNames.Length Then
            If txtUserInput.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
                ArrNames(I) = txtUserInput.Text
                I = I + 1

                lstDisplay.DataSource = Nothing
                lstDisplay.DataSource = ArrNames

                txtUserInput.Clear()
                txtUserInput.Focus()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a name first!")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("The array is full!")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend you to use typed Lists instead of using the old fashioned array (discussions incoming.. but..).

You can also make use of the nice feature of Enumerable.Range().

I don't have my editor right now but it should look like:

```
Dim list = new List(Of string)
For i In Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
   list.Add(txtUserInput.Text)
Next
txtUserInput.Clear()

lstDisplay.DataSource = list
```

If you plan to modify your list afterwards and e.g. keep it on class scope, then you should use a BindingList(Of String) which supports notifying about changes.

**Edit 1:**
You are calling `txtUserInput.Clear()` inside the loop after the first time your input has been received from the textbox. That means in each following iteration the textbox is cleared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'd love to use lists it would make the whole thing so much simpler but unfortunately this is an assignment that was given to me by my CS teacher so I am forced to use arrays ):

Comment: `For i In Enumerable.Range(1, 10)` I get an error on this line.

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to add the contents of the text box 10 times. Why would you repeat the same content 10 times?